# prevent pandas read_excel function from automatic converting boolean columns into float64

Tags: python, pandas

I have an Excel file which contains all the data I need to read into memory. Each row is a data sample and each column is a feature. I am using pandas.read_excel() function to read it.

The problem is that this function automatically converts some boolean columns into float64 type. I manually checked some columns. Only the columns with missing values are converted. The columns without missing values are still bool.

My question is: how can I prevent read_excel() function from automatically converting boolean columns into float64.

Here is my code snippet:

```
>>> fp = open('myfile.xlsx', 'rb')
>>> df = pd.read_excel(fp, header=0)
>>> df['BooleanFeature'].dtype
dtype('float64')
```

Here `BooleanFeature` is a boolean feature, but with some missing values.

Comment: You cannot prevent that. It is because nan's cannot be represented in boolean or integer arrays (see [gotchas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html))

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked, using a converter on all columns. The disadvantage in this solution is that the file is read twice to get all column names first:

```
def boolean_filter(value):
    if value == '':  # this seems to be causing the conversion problem, NAs are empty strings at this point
        return np.nan
    else:
        return value

df = pd.read_excel(file)
df = pd.read_excel(file, converters={col: boolean_filter for col in df.columns})
```